# How to add buffer in to a geo location

Tags: python, buffer, geopandas

I want to draw 200m buffer circle around two geo locations. I tried with below code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

locations = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': '1',
     'longitude': 50.604972,
     'latitude': 19.346815},
    {'id': '2',
     'longitude': 54.605917,
     'latitude': 18.347249}
])

locations_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(locations,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(locations.longitude,locations.latitude),crs='EPSG:32634')

locations_gpd.geometry = locations_gpd.geometry.buffer(200)
locations_gpd.plot()
```

I am getting only big circle after executing this code. How can I do this?

Comment: Your buffer is 200 degrees wide, you need to reproject to a projection in metres

Comment: I want to draw 200m circle around those geo locations.

Answer (score 4):

Your coordinates are lat long, you need to set the geometry to epsg 4326, then reproject to a crs with meters as units, then buffer:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

locations = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': '1',
     'longitude': 50.604972,
     'latitude': 19.346815},
    {'id': '2',
     'longitude': 54.605917,
     'latitude': 18.347249}
])

locations_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(locations,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(locations.longitude, locations.latitude),crs='EPSG:4326')
locations_gpd.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/locations_gpd_latlon.shp') #Export as a point shapefile

locations_gpd = locations_gpd.to_crs(32638) #Reproject
locations_gpd['geometry'] = locations_gpd['geometry'].buffer(200) #Buffer

locations_gpd.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/locations_gpd.shp') #Export as a polygon shapefile
```

[image]

Comment: how you generate those two shape files? I think I need those shape files to do this task.

Comment: It is all in the code. Using `.to_file`, just change the paths